# Does Merkaba relate to Kaabah in Mekkah?

Tags: arabic, kaabah

What is a Merkaba, its source, and how does it relate to the Kabah in Mekkah Saudi Arabia?

Comment: Here is a link to get an idea of what people nowadays think it means. But it hasn't really anything to do with islam because it's just some speculation of the word merkaba thought of as an anagram. https://thecasswiki.net/index.php?title=Merkaba

Comment: Merkaba is Marakab , a compound based on a root square , otherwise known as the constitution, the way, It is the way of the Pharaoh s, men justified as the lords, and adopted by the Jews to promote racism by faith. every one is borne equal by Allah the merciful, but they are divided by the crime of racism on purpose by the crooks of history, such as the Brahmans in Hinduism, Jews in Christianity and self proclaimed  Sayeds in Islam. Answer to the Merkabah is KabahtAllah in Mekkah Saudi Arabia, A Constant, not a square according to the crooks of Pharaoh ism in Egypt, in a form a  pyramid.

Comment: @MohammadDar you should add any info to your post comments are not meant to stay forever.

Comment: If you are willing to provide a Email address, I will send my research paper on this subject. Judaism is related to the Pharaoh ism, The Hinduism, based on the Merkabah, recorded in Bible as the Vision of Chariot (Shariat in Arabic and Latin)  Azekah, or   meaning "The constitution", and the foundation of the Christianity as a faith.

Answer (score 1):

[Merkabah](http://biblehub.com/str/hebrew/4818.htm) in hebrew is the feminine of [merkab](http://biblehub.com/hebrew/4817.htm) which means chariots, it is derived from [rakab](http://biblehub.com/hebrew/7392.htm) which is the same as the arabic root [ر ك ب](http://corpus.quran.com/qurandictionary.jsp?q=rkb) meaning *ride*.

It has no apparent connection to Makkah or Kaabah, that I am aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Merkabah or Markabah مركبة -in Arabic language- is a -feminine- word referring to an object that can be ridden as it comes from the root or verb رَكِبَ (rakiba) to ride. It may refer to a ship a chariot or even a spacecraft. In the Qur'an this verb was mostly used in context of ships see for example in ([11:42](https://legacy.quran.com/11/42)), ([18:71](https://legacy.quran.com/11/42)) and ([29:65](https://legacy.quran.com/29/65)) where it mostly appears in the story of Nuh () with the exception of the story of Musa () and al-Khidr () in surat al-Kahf.
The quran also uses other derivatives such as الرَّكب which is referring to a big amount of people riding animals etc. like  a caravan ([8:42](https://legacy.quran.com/8/42)) and the word رِكَاب which is a synonym of camel ([59:6](https://legacy.quran.com/59/6)).

Note that the verb (rakkaba) رَكٌّب usually means to assemble and has a different root, so don't confound them.

[Al-Ka'abah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaaba) الكعبة in Mekka is named or is a -feminine- derivative of it's geometrical form المكعب (al-Muka'ab) a cube!

Answer (score -1):

Merkabah and Kabahtallah are in opposition to each other, Merkabh represents a constitution (Way) practiced by the pagans in racism, self centered by faith, and Kabahtallah represents a constitution, based on and commanded by  Allah (St), Al, The, La, Limit, h most high, The Lord, in accordance to the creation, The truth (Allah (St) as its foundation to enjoy life within Islam, limit of perfection, the truth.